# Java - insert shuffled list inside 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I insert my shuffled list inside a 2D array?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=1; i<17; i++) {
    list.add(new Integer(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(list);

for (int c=0; c<16 ; c++) {
    String number;
    number = Integer.toString(list.get(c));
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            JButton btnmix = new JButton();
            btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the last number of the printing:

```
[0][0] 2                                         [0][0] 4                                       
[0][1] 2                                         [0][1] 16
[0][2] 2                                         [0][2] 12
[0][3] 2                                         [0][3] 6
[1][0] 2                                         [1][0] 11
[1][1] 2                                         [1][1] 7
[1][2] 2                                         [1][2] 3
[1][3] 2    What Im trying to acomplish ---->    [1][3] 14
[2][0] 2                                         [2][0] 5
[2][1] 2                                         [2][1] 15
[2][2] 2                                         [2][2] 9
[2][3] 2                                         [2][3] 10
[3][0] 2                                         [3][0] 13
[3][1] 2                                         [3][1] 1
[3][2] 2                                         [3][2] 8
[3][3] 2                                         [3][3] 2
```

but when I print my number variable inside the cicle, I get all my non-repeated shuffled list in disorder (as it's mean to be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting each button 16 times, because you have the code inside 3 for loops. Each iteration of the outer for loop, the button text gets set to another number, but it's the same for all buttons in the iteration. So it will end up being the number from the last iteration.

Try this instead:

```
int c = 0;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        String number = Integer.toString(list.get(c));
        c++;

        JButton btnmix = new JButton();
        btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
        btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to calculate `c` with `i * 4 + j`